# Is it possible to change the number of vcores used inside your driver class?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have submitted a MR job over Yarn and it uses only 2 vcores, hence slow.

I have set `conf.set("mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores", "35");`  in my driver code i.e

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
GenericOptionsParser optionParser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);
String[] remainingArgs = optionParser.getRemainingArgs();
if (!(remainingArgs.length != 2 || remainingArgs.length != 4)) {
    System.err.println("Usage: DataProcessorMR <in> <out> <config> <daten-tool>");
    System.exit(2);
}
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "DataProcessorMR");
job.setJarByClass(DataProcessorMR.class);
job.setMapperClass(DPMapper.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
job.addCacheFile(new Path(args[2]).toUri());
job.addCacheFile(new Path(args[3]).toUri());
conf.set("mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores", "35");
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

But this has no effect on the Yarn Resource Manager? How do I set the number of VCORES for YARN MapReduce job inside java class.

Comment: conf.set("mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores", "35"); 
should be set before

Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "DataProcessorMR");

Comment: did it improve performance of your job?? I doubt that.

Comment: @shekhar not really. it is still using 2 cores. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Do I have to write a Yarn application for this?

Comment: in capacity-scheduler.xml set -> yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
After this you will see 70 cores used on YARN UI in scheduler tab.

Comment: This should work for the capacity scheduler. What if fair scheduling is enabled on the  cluster and also one may not be allowed to make cluster level changes. There should be something that a map reduce job can use and tell YARN that it wants to use more number of cores for their map tasks. Usually 1 core per map task is sufficient when processing a block, but for CPU bound map tasks one might require more number of cores.

Comment: If you are running threads in your job, OS will handle it. If you want to control it using yarn then you need to set vcores.

Comment: Is there a way I can specify the number of vcores for YARN in my MapReduce driver class? Like the way we do it in a Spark driver or Spark submit.

Comment: you can't change yarn configs in job, you can set resources required for your container like conf.set("mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores", "35");